# How to select a range of elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="myDiv">
     <a>...</a>
     <a>...</a>
     <a>...</a>
     <a>...</a>
     <a>...</a>
     <a>...</a>
</div>
```

If you wanted to select the 2nd, 3rd and 4th `a` tags in the above example, how would you do that? The only thing I can think of is:

```
$("#myDiv a:eq(1), #myDiv a:eq(2), #myDiv a:eq(3)")
```

But that doesn't look to be very efficient or pretty. I guess you could also select ALL the `a`s and then do run `.each` over them, but that could get very inefficient if there were a lot more `a`s.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

jQuery [slice()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/slice) function taking indexes of the first and the last needed elements selects a subset of the matched elements. Note what it doesn't include last element itself.

In your particular case you should use

```
$("#myDiv a").slice(1, 4)
```

Comment: `$('.className').slice(1, 4)` can also be useful, that's what I needed for my scenario, many thanks for getting the train of thought started :)

Comment: Does such a broad initial selection add processing overhead, compared to a more specific selector? Or do you think :lt, :gt, and :eq are more resource-intensive?

Comment: Great. This works for selecting multiple options form select element as well.

Answer (score 10):

Using the [.slice()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/slice) function does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this by extracting a slice of the array thus.  It's the line

```
$("div[id='myDiv'] > a").slice(1,4).css("background","yellow");
```

that you're interested in.  It will affect the 2nd, 3rd and 4th elements.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("a").click(function(event){
                    $("div[id='myDiv'] > a").slice(1,4).css("background","yellow");
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv">
            <a>1</a>
            <a>2</a>
            <a>3</a>
            <a>4</a>
            <a>5</a>
            <a>6</a>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <a href="" >Click here</a>
        <hr>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that ID selection is extremely inefficient. You should use the `$("#myDiv")` syntax instead.