# How to style 3rd, 4th or 5th table cell using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I know to style odd / even table cells using jQuery, but how do i style the 3rd, 4th or 5th element?

```
<table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="Weekdays">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Week Day</td>
    <td>Short Name</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Monday</td>
    <td>Mon</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
    <td>Tue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td>Wed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Thursday</td>
    <td>Thr</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Friday</td>
    <td>Fri</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Saturday</td>
    <td>Sat</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sunday</td>
    <td>Sun</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How do i do it?

Comment: Similiar to how to select a range: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185966/how-to-select-a-range-of-elements-in-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using eq():

```
$('td:eq(5)').css('background','red');

// OR:

$('td').eq(5).css('background','red');
```

Both of those examples would color the 6th TD element's background in red.

Comment: Used this instead

$('#Weekdays tbody tr:eq(5)').css('background','#F2C2C2');
worked perfectly for me. Thank you.

Comment: Accept his answer if its the one you used !

Comment: How do i style every 5th alternate cell?????
Ex: first 5 then 10th then 15th and so on....

Comment: @chriszero Check my example. It's loop length is the amount of TD/5 while your's is 5 times longer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to literally get an element range (though I'm not 100% sure that's what you're after), like this:

```
$("td").slice(2, 5).css("color", "red");​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5BrrA/) this would select the following elements:

- `<td>Monday</td>`
- `<td>Mon</td>`
- `<td>Tuesday</td>`

So I'm not sure what you mean by the element, [here's a version using rows](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5BrrA/1/), just swap `"td"` for `"tr"` to get this.

Comment: I learn something new every day. That slice function is pretty handy.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Weekdays tbody tr').each(function(i) {
   // Modify the style of element i here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr:nth-child(5)').function();
```

Theres a lot of things you don't know about CS3 :) http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: nth-child(5) selects the 6th child in TD and not the 6th TD

Answer (score 0):

To select childs from nth to last child of any element, simply use:

```
$("#mytable td").slice(n).hide()
```