# jquery :gt() inclusive

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I was wondering how to use jQuery's :gt() in an inclusive way. I am trying to show/hide table rows dynamically.

```
$('#' + tbodyId + ' > tr:gt(' + newRowStart + '):lt(' + rowsToShow + ')').show();
```

If i try to show the first 5 rows say, `newRowStart = 0` and `rowsToShow = 5`. This will not show the first row. Setting it to -1 doesn't work either. It would be very helpful if there was an inclusive method like :gte(). Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$('#'+tbodyId)
  .find('tr')
  .slice( newRowStart, newRowStart + rowsToShow ) // inclusive of starting point
  .show();
```

Comment: Is $('#'+tbodyId).find('tr') better than $('#'+tbodyId + ' > tr')? My table cells might include tables which is why i needed the '>'. Does your way not get all tr children?

Comment: @Timothy, I prefer it because it's easier to read (in my opinion). But if you have nested tables, then you're right -- you'd have to use `>` in the selector *or* perhaps `children()`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want the slice function:

[How to select a range of elements in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185966/how-to-select-a-range-of-elements-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

use below way..( just a way i suggesting) u can manipulate according to your need

```
$(".someClass").filter(":eq("+ N + "), :gt(" + N + ")")"
```

Answer (score 0):

A stab in the dark:

```
$('#' + tbodyId + ' > tr:not(:lt(' + newRowStart + ')):lt(' + rowsToShow + ')').show();
```