# jquery selectors - selecting by the order number

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select a range of elements in jQuery.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185966/how-to-select-a-range-of-elements-in-jquery)

How do I select paragraph by there's order?

e.g first 4 I can select by

```
('#main p:lt(4)');
```

but how can I select paragraph from 5 to 8, from 8 to 12 etc.. ?

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <p>text1</p>
    <p>text2</p>
    <p>text3</p>
    <p>text4</p>
    <p>text5</p>
    <p>text6</p>
    <p>text7</p>
    <p>text8</p>
    <p>text9</p>
    <p>text10</p>
    <p>text11</p>
    <p>text12</p>
</div>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Pete

Comment: You can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185966/how-to-select-a-range-of-elements-in-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5 to 8 is greter then 4 and lower then 9:

```
$('#main p:gt(4):lt(9)');
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('#main p:gt(4):lt(9)')` will select p 5 to 8.

Using `$('#main p').slice(4, 7)` would probably be faster though.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `gt` too:

```
$('#main p:gt(4):lt(9)');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) the entire set ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/GcHCT/)):

```
$('.main p').slice(<start>, <end>);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `slice(start, end)`

```
$("#main p").slice(5, 8) ;
```