# JQuery get the nth element of array

Tags: jquery, arrays

```
$('#button').click(function() {
   alert($('.column').val());
});
```

How could I get the first, second, or third element in `.column`?

Comment: You want the first, second, OR third meaning any of the three? Or do you want all of them? And are you referring to three elements with the class `.column`, or three elements *within* a parent `.column` element?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    alert($('.column').eq(0).val()); // first element
    alert($('.column').eq(1).val()); // second
    alert($('.column').eq(2).val()); // third
});
```

Comment: Just as documentation: _"Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index."_  [jQuery.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 6):

I like selector strings, so I usually do this:

```
$('.column:eq(3)') // Fourth .column element
```

Comment: I like them purely for style but it should be noted that the jQuery docs recommend .eq() over :eq() for performance on modern browsers: http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Answer (score 3):

Use the Slice() function:
http://api.jquery.com/slice/

See question:
[How to select a range of elements in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185966/how-to-select-a-range-of-elements-in-jquery)

```
$('.column').slice(0, 2).each(function() {
    $(this).val();  /* my value */
});
```

Comment: Slice could do it, but that function is really ideal for selecting a range if indices. Surely there is a function optimal for selecting a single index?

Comment: you mean like nth-child or eq()?  You said you wanted the first 3, maybe I misunderstood but that seems to be the definition of a range of indices?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `:lt` (less-than) selector and tell it you want `0, 1, and 2` by indicating all `.column` elements below index `3`:

```
$("#button").on("click", function(){
  $(".column:lt(3)").each(function(){
    alert( this.value );
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/icevih/edit#javascript,html