# How to select 2nd to 4th td from a row inside jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-selectors

I have a table of checkboxes and I want to select the 2nd to 4th td from a row of 7 tds.
Specifically I want to select the input:checkboxes of the 2nd to 4th td, of the first row in a table,

My code so far

```
$('tr:nth-child(1) td:gt(2) input:checkbox')
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: you should add a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select a range of elements in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185966/how-to-select-a-range-of-elements-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `slice` method:

```
$('tr:first td').slice(1, 4).find('input[type=checkbox]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(-n + 4):nth-child(n + 2) input:checkbox')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/erWp9/2/

Comment: It looks great and it works great on your code but on mine no. Mine is var $radio5 = $('tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(-n + 4):nth-child(n + 2) input:checkbox'); 
   $radio5.change(function(){
     var $group = $radio5;
     if($(this).is(':checked')){
         $group.not($(this)).prop('checked',false);
     }
    });  Any idea why it doesn;t work?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr td').filter(function(){
    return $(this).index() > 0 && $(this).index() < 4;
});
```

[Here's your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggUZy/)

Answer (score -1):

You better rely on the jquery's methods:

```
$("tr").eq(1).find("td").find("input[type='checkbox']")
and
$("tr").eq(3).find("td").find("input[type='checkbox']")
```