# Jquery selecting a range

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table, I'm looking to select the the `nth-child(3)` - `nth-child(9)`,
is their a way to select between a range in jQuery/CSS? I was going to hard code each one, but I know there has to be a cleaner way to do this?

Any thoughts?

The table:

```
<table>
 <thead>
     <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
</tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
</tr>
 </tbody>
```

Comment: you should really at least post the code you tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select a range of elements in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185966/how-to-select-a-range-of-elements-in-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [:gt()](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) and [:lt()](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

```
$('table tbody td:gt(1):lt(7)')
```

> `:gt(1):lt(7)` select element after 2nd element (index starts from 0 so :gt(1) refers to 2nd element) that is start from 3rd
>   element and select next 7 elements

---

[.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```
$('table thead th').slice(2, 9)
```

> `.slice(2, 9)` select element after 2nd element that is start from 3rd
>   element till 9th element (including 9th element)

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/huW5r/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Sure. You can use jQuery's [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) function, as follows:

```
var subset = $('table tbody td').slice(3, 6);
```

Or you can combine the `:gt()` and `:lt()` selectors as follows:

```
var subset = $('table tbody td:gt(2):lt(10)');
```

**Please note:** The selectors I have provided are arbitrary to demonstrate correct syntax. You didn't specify which elements you wanted to select, so you might need to update the selectors accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("tr:first").find("th").slice(2,9).addClass("select");
$("tr:gt(0)").each(function(){
    $(this).find("td").slice(2,9).addClass("select");
});
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ng4uT/)

Comment: This works, but I think the OP wanted to avoid creating the full array first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
---css---

td{
   border: 1px solid; 
   min-width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
}

---javascript---

```
$( "td" ).slice( 3, 9 ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

You can see demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/yuPaF/).