# How to select the last X items in a list with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Given the following html:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item ADD</li>
</ul>
```

Using jQuery, how can I dynamically select the last X items, excluding the last item. For example example, for 3, how I can set css on the last 3 items excluding the last item.:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li style="background:red;">Item 6</li>
    <li style="background:red;">Item 7</li>
    <li style="background:red;">Item 8</li>
    <li>Item ADD</li>
</ul>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

Use a combination of `:gt()` with a negative index, `:not`, and `:last`:

```
$('li:gt(-5):not(:last)').css('color','red');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/aWMCF/)**

Answer (score 4):

Use jQuery's .slice() method.

See here: [How to select a range of elements in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185966/how-to-select-a-range-of-elements-in-jquery)

```
$("ul li").slice(5,8)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x //The number of children you want
var n = $("ul > li").size()
n = n-1 //this prevents taking the last one 
for ( var i = x; i > 0; i-- ) {
   $( "ul li:nth-child(n-i)" ).append( "<style>etc." );
}
```